# Loop over a range of numbers to download with wget

Tags: bash, shell-script, wget

How can I write a bash script that is going to do the following:

```
URL = "example.com/imageID="
while (1..100)
   wget URL + $i #it will wget example.com/imageID=1, then 2, then 3, etc
done
```

So I have a number of loops to perform, a URL which is ended with a number from the loop. I need to `wget` all of these.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

if you are using Bash 4.0, you can do this:

```
wget example.com/imageId={1..100}.jpg
```

Answer (score 15):

It's fairly easy, even for someone with not much programming experience. When in doubt always read the [Bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) manual:

```
for i in {1..100}
do
    wget "example.com/imageID=$i"
done
```

Comment: As a matter of principle, you should enclose the `$i` in quotes: `wget "example.com/imageID=$i"`

Comment: this probably works great. however, i start from "00008000" and the wget shoots errors because for some reasn it skips the first four zeroes.

Comment: @esaruoho that's because "00008000" parses as the number 8000 - i'd solve that with either padding/number formatting (do all your "numbers" have eight characters?) or, if they all start with `0000`, start from 8 and add the extra zeroes into the quoted string `"example.com/imageID=0000$i"`

Answer (score 1):

In case variable is not at end of URL and variable is between underscores:
example.com/imageID_1_2018.gif
example.com/imageID_2_2018.gif
example.com/imageID_3_2018.gif
.
.
.
example.com/imageID_100_2018.gif

`wget example.com/imageID_{1..100}_2018.gif`
equivalently:
`for ((i=1;i<=100;i++)); do wget example.com/imageID_${i}_2018.gif; done`

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please [edit] your answer to provide more detail. Not everyone reading your post may understand how it answers the OP's question without a more detailed explanation.

Comment: I’m not sure this *is* an answer.  It looks like an explanation of the accepted answer (and not a very clear one).

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is great.  I used something similar to download in parallel which may be useful:

```
echo example.com/imageId={1..100}.jpg | xargs -n 1 -P 10 wget
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also automatically add the leading zeros if necessary:

```
wget example.com/imageID_{001..100}_2018.gif
```

like

```
example.com/imageID_001_2018.gif
```

instead of

```
example.com/imageID_1_2018.gif
```